# Chaincode is not making state correctly?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

After Instantiating Fabcar Chaincode I tried to run functions of it using these commands.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myc -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["initLedger"]}
```

On this command, chaincode logs were like this.

> 2019-05-11T06:37:56.994Z info [lib/handler.js]
>   info: [myc-22dd9c0b] Calling chaincode Init() succeeded.
>   Sending COMPLETED message back to peer
>   {"timestamp":"2019-05-11T06:37:56.994Z"} { fcn: 'initLedger', params:
>   [] }
>   ============= START : Initialize Ledger =========== successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make:
>   'Toyota',   model: 'Prius',   color: 'blue',   owner: 'Tomoko',
>   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:
>    } Added <-->  { make: 'Ford',   model: 'Mustang',   color:
>   'red',   owner: 'Brad',   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200,
>   message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make: 'Hyundai',
>   model: 'Tucson',   color: 'green',   owner: 'Jin Soo',   docType:
>   'car' } successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:  }
>   Added <-->  { make: 'Volkswagen',   model: 'Passat',   color:
>   'yellow',   owner: 'Max',   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200,
>   message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make: 'Tesla',
>   model: 'S',   color: 'black',   owner: 'Adriana',   docType: 'car' }
>   successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:  } Added <-->
>   { make: 'Peugeot',   model: '205',   color: 'purple',   owner:
>   'Michel',   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200, message: '',
>   payload:  } Added <-->  { make: 'Chery',   model: 'S22L',
>   color: 'white',   owner: 'Aarav',   docType: 'car' } successful {
>   status: 200, message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make:
>   'Fiat',   model: 'Punto',   color: 'violet',   owner: 'Pari',
>   docType: 'car' } successful { status: 200, message: '', payload:
>    } Added <-->  { make: 'Tata',   model: 'Nano',   color:
>   'indigo',   owner: 'Valeria',   docType: 'car' } successful { status:
>   200, message: '', payload:  } Added <-->  { make: 'Holden',
>   model: 'Barina',   color: 'brown',   owner: 'Shotaro',   docType:
>   'car' }
>   ============= END : Initialize Ledger ===========

On this comand peer logs was like this.

> 2019-05-12 02:44:18.189 UTC [vscc] Validate -> ERRO 197 VSCC error:
>   stateBasedValidator.Validate failed, err validation of endorsement
>   policy for chaincode fabcar in tx 8:0 failed: signature set did not
>   satisfy policy 2019-05-12 02:44:18.189 UTC [committer.txvalidator]
>   validateTx -> ERRO 198 VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId
>   = 9e55c9bb42c109dc5236fedc58c1db95d46f02139525ccb6a6a4b9c9ec72743d returned error: validation of endorsement policy for chaincode fabcar
>   in tx 8:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy 2019-05-12
>   02:44:18.189 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 199
>   [myc] Validated block [8] in 28ms 2019-05-12 02:44:18.196 UTC
>   [valimpl] preprocessProtoBlock -> WARN 19a Channel [myc]:
>   Block [8] Transaction index [0] TxId
>   [9e55c9bb42c109dc5236fedc58c1db95d46f02139525ccb6a6a4b9c9ec72743d]
>   marked as invalid by committer. Reason code
>   [ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE] 2019-05-12 02:44:19.473 UTC [kvledger]
>   CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 19b [myc] Committed block [8] with 1
>   transaction(s) in 1277ms (state_validation=0ms block_commit=670ms
>   state_commit=420ms)

Then I tried to run the queryallCars method like this.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myc -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["queryAllCars"]}
```

On this command chaincode logs were like this.

> 2019-05-11T06:39:25.449Z info [lib/handler.js]
>   info: [myc-88655c1f] Calling chaincode Invoke() succeeded.
>   Sending COMPLETED message back to peer
>   {"timestamp":"2019-05-11T06:39:25.449Z"} { fcn: 'queryAllCars',
>   params: [] } end of data [] 2019-05-11T06:41:50.560Z info
>   [lib/handler.js]

After I tried to retrieve a one car using queryCar method like this.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myc -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["queryCar","CAR0"]}'
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"transaction returned with failure: Error: CAR0 does not exist:
```

On this command chaincode logs is like this.

> { fcn: 'queryCar', params: [ 'CAR0' ] } Error: CAR0 does not exist:
>       at queryCar (/usr/local/src/fabcar.js:50:13)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) 2019-05-11T06:43:32.844Z error [lib/handler.js]
>   error: [myc-4b24ad23] Calling chaincode Invoke() returned
>   error response [Error: CAR0 does not exist: ]. Sending ERROR message
>   back

I tried a lot to figure it out what is wrong with chain code but I was unable to do so.

This is my chaincode.

```
/*
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/

"use strict";
const shim = require("fabric-shim");
const util = require("util");

let Chaincode = class {
  // The Init method is called when the Smart Contract 'fabcar' is instantiated by the blockchain network
  // Best practice is to have any Ledger initialization in separate function -- see initLedger()
  async Init(stub) {
    console.info("=========== Instantiated fabcar chaincode ===========");
    return shim.success();
  }

  // The Invoke method is called as a result of an application request to run the Smart Contract
  // 'fabcar'. The calling application program has also specified the particular smart contract
  // function to be called, with arguments
  async Invoke(stub) {
    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info(ret);

    let method = this[ret.fcn];
    if (!method) {
      console.error("no function of name:" + ret.fcn + " found");
      throw new Error("Received unknown function " + ret.fcn + " invocation");
    }
    try {
      let payload = await method(stub, ret.params);
      return shim.success(payload);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return shim.error(err);
    }
  }

  async queryCar(stub, args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error(
        "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting CarNumber ex: CAR01"
      );
    }
    let carNumber = args[0];

    let carAsBytes = await stub.getState(carNumber); //get the car from chaincode state
    if (!carAsBytes || carAsBytes.toString().length <= 0) {
      throw new Error(carNumber + " does not exist: ");
    }
    console.log(carAsBytes.toString());
    return carAsBytes;
  }

  async initLedger(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Initialize Ledger ===========");
    let cars = [];
    cars.push({
      make: "Toyota",
      model: "Prius",
      color: "blue",
      owner: "Tomoko"
    });
    cars.push({
      make: "Ford",
      model: "Mustang",
      color: "red",
      owner: "Brad"
    });
    cars.push({
      make: "Hyundai",
      model: "Tucson",
      color: "green",
      owner: "Jin Soo"
    });
    cars.push({
      make: "Volkswagen",
      model: "Passat",
      color: "yellow",
      owner: "Max"
    });
    cars.push({
      make: "Tesla",
      model: "S",
      color: "black",
      owner: "Adriana"
    });
    cars.push({
      make: "Peugeot",
      model: "205",
      color: "purple",
      owner: "Michel"
    });
    cars.push({
      make: "Chery",
      model: "S22L",
      color: "white",
      owner: "Aarav"
    });
    cars.push({
      make: "Fiat",
      model: "Punto",
      color: "violet",
      owner: "Pari"
    });
    cars.push({
      make: "Tata",
      model: "Nano",
      color: "indigo",
      owner: "Valeria"
    });
    cars.push({
      make: "Holden",
      model: "Barina",
      color: "brown",
      owner: "Shotaro"
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      cars[i].docType = "car";
      await stub.putState("CAR" + i, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(cars[i]))).then(
        () => {
          console.info("successful");
          console.log(shim.success());
        },
        () => {
          console.log(shim.error());
        }
      );
      console.info("Added <--> ", cars[i]);
    }
    console.info("============= END : Initialize Ledger ===========");
  }

  async createCar(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Create Car ===========");
    if (args.length != 5) {
      throw new Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 5");
    }

    var car = {
      docType: "car",
      make: args[1],
      model: args[2],
      color: args[3],
      owner: args[4]
    };

    await stub.putState(args[0], Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(car)));
    console.info("============= END : Create Car ===========");
  }

  async queryAllCars(stub, args) {
    let startKey = "CAR0";
    let endKey = "CAR999";

    let iterator = await stub.getStateByRange(startKey, endKey);

    let allResults = [];
    while (true) {
      let res = await iterator.next();

      if (res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
        let jsonRes = {};
        console.log(res.value.value.toString("utf8"));

        jsonRes.Key = res.value.key;
        try {
          jsonRes.Record = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString("utf8"));
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          jsonRes.Record = res.value.value.toString("utf8");
        }
        allResults.push(jsonRes);
      }
      if (res.done) {
        console.log("end of data");
        await iterator.close();
        console.info(allResults);
        return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(allResults));
      }
    }
  }

  async changeCarOwner(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : changeCarOwner ===========");
    if (args.length != 2) {
      throw new Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2");
    }

    let carAsBytes = await stub.getState(args[0]);
    let car = JSON.parse(carAsBytes);
    car.owner = args[1];

    await stub.putState(args[0], Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(car)));
    console.info("============= END : changeCarOwner ===========");
  }
};

shim.start(new Chaincode());
```

This is package.json file.

```
{
    "name": "fabcar",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "fabcar chaincode implemented in node.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=8.4.0",
        "npm": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node fabcar.js"
    },
    "engine-strict": true,
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "fabric-shim": "~1.4.0"
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you did not get an error on the initial `peer chaincode invoke ... ` command?  Seems like the transaction was likely not committed

Comment: @GariSingh on the chaincode logs It was succsfull But on the peer logs there was an error. I update the question with It.

Answer (score 0):

@dwp transaction failed during the validation at peer side , you can see VSCC error.

Comment: yeah.Can you tell me what kind of reson lead to this kind of error?

Comment: may be same key is updated on the transaction which is being recently updated by any other transaction, kind of transaction validation failed